# Linux ARSystem data connection

Tags: linux, odbc, remedy

I deal with an ARSystem and I've been accessing the arserver data by ODBC communication using the AR System driver for Windows plataform. I would like to do the same on a linux plataform. My specifications to do the connection at the ODBC Manager Setup are:

```
Data Source Name

AR Server

User name

Password

(checked choices)

Replace '.' in object names

Use underscores
```

Is it possible? How can I do that?
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is an ARSystem ODBC driver for Linux. You could use an ODBC-ODBC Bridge to get at it from Linux.

Comment: Is there a free solution?

Comment: There are no free bridges I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the [JDBC](https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-22516) Driver for Remedy or [ARSPerl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/arsperl/) if it has to run in a shell. Both of those solutions can be run on Windows as well.